# How to count the values in duplicated rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Although this seems like an easy problem I have be struggling with it for a while. I have two dataframes that I want to determine the duplicates between with respect to certain columns and then I want to sum the values of the the both dataframes with respect to another column. I will do my best to show. The following tables describe the structure of the two dataframes, I will call then df1 and df2.

| make | 2019-12-01 | 2019-06-04 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | 0 | 3 |
| VW | 1 | 3 |

| make | 2018-12-01 | 2019-06-04 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TESLA | 0 | 2 |
| VW | 2 | 2 |

this is my attempt

```
df = pd.concat ([df1, df2], axis=1)
    df_2 = df [df.duplicated (subset=[ 'make'], keep=False)]
    df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_2)
    valuePosition1 = df_2.columns.get_loc(2019-12-01)
    valuePosition2 = df_2.columns.get_loc(2018-12-01)
    flow = min(df_2.iloc[:, valuePosition1].sum(), df_2.iloc[:, valuePosition2].sum())
    print(flow)
```

the answer should be 1, as there is a VW in both df1[2019-12-01] and df2[2018-12-01]. But I keep getting weird errors:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Which doesn't even seem to understand what I am doing. I am really at my wits end. Both dataframes are also very big so I would need a quick way to do it.

Any guidance or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you include all the relevant code please? Where df.duplicated defined etc. And be carefull with the spacing "get_loc (2019-12-01)".

Comment: Ah thank you. duplicated is a function of pandas that I found. I will include a link. I hope that is what you are asking.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Answer (score 0):

It is better to concatenate along the row axis (`concat(..., axis=0)`) since [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) expects to work along that axis:

> Return boolean Series denoting duplicate rows.

You can also use `loc` (which is primarily label based) rather than `iloc` (which is primarily integer position based) considering you know the columns you're interested in.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('sample1.csv', sep='\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', sep='\s+')

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)
print(df)

dfd = df[df.duplicated(subset=['make'], keep=False)]
print(dfd)

flow = min(dfd.loc[:, '2019-12-01'].sum(),
           dfd.loc[:, '2018-12-01'].sum())
print(flow)
```

Output from *df*

```py
    make  2019-12-01  2019-06-04  2018-12-01
0    BMW         0.0           3         NaN
1     VW         1.0           3         NaN
0  TESLA         NaN           2         0.0
1     VW         NaN           2         2.0
```

Output from *dfd*

```py
  make  2019-12-01  2019-06-04  2018-12-01
1   VW         1.0           3         NaN
1   VW         NaN           2         2.0
```

Output from *flow*

```
1.0
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is really helpful !